# Fixing game loop to 60fps makes animation very jittery

Tags: java, game-design, game-loop

ns is 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;

```
    long now = System.nanoTime();
    delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
    lastTime = now;

    if (delta >= 1) { 
        tick(glad);
        updates++;
        delta--;
        fps_counter = 0;
    }

    if (delta >= fps_counter / FramesPerTick) { // render
        fps_counter++;
        frames++;
        render(glad);
    }

    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
        timer += 1000;
        frame.setTitle("Ticks: " + updates + " Fps: " + frames);
        updates = 0;
        frames = 0;
    }
```

So if i have 20 ticks and 3 FramesPerTick i get 60fps
it checks whenever delta is bigger than 1/3, 2/3 and 3/3, so every tick has 3 frames

Everything is jittery, movement, mouse look.
Animation gets more and more jittery the lower the FPS, i dont understand why.

Also when i take the render(glad) method out of the if, it goes up to 400 fps and runs very smoothly.

EDIT:
If i put Thread.sleep(13) instead of if (delta>=fpscounter/FramesPerTick){} i get around 60 fps and smooth animations.

Comment: Sounds like you've got vertical synchronization enabled and at the same time try to control your rendered framerate yourself. What happens if you set the condition of the render `if()` to `true`?

Comment: @Mario if its true then ill use the full potential of the CPU producing 400-500 fps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah! I missed the obvious reason for the odd behavior while first looking at your code (I think). Essentially, there are three potential problems here:

### First: Missing Updates

Each and every iteration you'll update your game logic only once (or not at all). In a similar way, you draw your screen (or skip drawing).

However, this causes one problem:

- Let's assume you'd like to update the game 100 times per second (makes it easier to explain/compare).
- This means there are 10 ms between updates.
- As long as each and every iteration is faster than 10 ms, you won't notice any problem.
- Now assume there's some stuttering for a moment (don't know, let's say you connected some device or whatever).
- This iteration, 25 ms have passed. This means that you'd have to do two updates before rendering again, i.e. `update(); update(); render();`.
- Due to your design, you won't do this. Instead you'll get `update(); render(); update(); render();`.
- This might cause visual/noticeable stuttering (especially if we're talking about more than just two updates!) since the game now obviously lags a bit (till you've cleared your update backlog; assuming you're able to do so).
- This also means you're essentially connecting your logic updates to the framerate. If you can't render at the intentional framerate, your game logic will slow down as well.

### Second: Race Conditions

This is something you can't really avoid if you'd like to do fixed timesteps:

- Let's assume you're rendering 60 times per second and updating 30 times per second.
- Theoretically, this should trigger one call to `update()` for every second call to `render()`.
- However, this is essentially just an average number.
- It's possible, that between two frames you miss your update since you're like 5 ns too fast.
- Rather than calling `update(); render(); render(); update(); render(); render();` you'd at once call `update(), render(); render(); render(); update(); render();`. Overall you're still at 60/30 fps, but your timing is still off a bit (especially if you've got vertical sync enabled).
- This can cause minor inconsistencies that might become noticeable, especially when things on screen are moving quite fast.
- [Fix Your Timestep!](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) elaborates a bit more and also provides a solution to this.

### Third: Rounding/Precision Issues

While I can't say this for sure, you might be running into precision issues with your variables.

If `delta` is some floating point variable (due to the `/ ns` step?), you might run into rounding issues here.

Also [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) doesn't necessarily return a very precise time value - it's implementation dependent. It could be in nanoseconds, but it could as well just return whole milliseconds or even less (could also depend on the system's energy saving settings):

> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as that of currentTimeMillis().

Depending on your actual number of frames/updates this might be neglectable though. (And there isn't really anything you can do about this, other than trying to pick sane numbers/scaling that will work for you.)

Comment: First of all thank you for your comprehensive answer, you explained things very good.
1) I dont think rendering would be too slow because i get 400 FPS means 2,5ms for a frame.
2) On the other hand (if i understood corectly) i think this is the problem since i get free time after the frames and instead of calling Render() again i wait for Update(). This explains when i use Thread.sleep(13) working smoothly.